# Arithmetic Overflow When Adding Hyphen To Varchar Values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am getting the below error

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 6, Line 5< br>
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

This is sample DDL that illustrates my issue.  How would a query be set-up that can achieve such?

```
Declare @Teetotal As Table (ramalad varchar(500))

Insert Into @Teetotal (ramalad) Values ('200.4'), ('300.12')

Select ramalad
,ManipulatedData = CAST(ramalad AS DECIMAL(16,2)) + ' - ' + (CAST(ramalad As DECIMAL(10,2))/25)*3
FROM @Teetotal
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.  The code doesn't make sense.  Why would use do arithmetic operations on a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're trying to add a string to a decimal:

```
CAST(ramalad AS DECIMAL(16,2)) + ' - '
```

SQL does not know how to convert `' - '` to a number, so it raises an error.

Maybe what you want is:

```
ManipulatedData = ramalad + ' - ' + CAST( (CAST(ramalad As DECIMAL(10,2))/25) *3 as varchar)
```

Comment: I need to have the hyphen between the two values.  Is there a way to encode it so that it's possible?

Comment: @uncoder @IcyPopTarts - Suggested edit to improve this slightly: use `CONCAT` like this: `ManipulatedData = concat(ramalad, ' - ', (CAST(ramalad As DECIMAL(10,2))/25) *3)`.  I find concat handles NULL better in some cases (evaluates to empty string instead of nulling all added strings)